# Why lift can't find my "db.properties"

Tags: classpath, lift

In a lift project, I put the db configurations in a file called `db.properties`

```
/src/main/resources/db.properties
```

And in my `Boot.scala`, I read it as:

```
val input = this.getClass.getResourceAsStream("db.properties")
println("### input: " +input)

val db = new java.util.Properties
db.load(input)

val url = db.getProperty("url")  
println("#### url:" + url)
```

Then I start sbt:

```
sbt prepare-web jetty-start
```

The console prints some errors:

```
### input: null
21:48:55.906 [main] ERROR n.liftweb.http.provider.HTTPProvider - Failed to Boot! Your application may not run properly
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at java.util.Properties$LineReader.readLine(Properties.java:418) ~[na:1.6.0_27]
    at java.util.Properties.load0(Properties.java:337) ~[na:1.6.0_27]
    at java.util.Properties.load(Properties.java:325) ~[na:1.6.0_27]
    at bootstrap.liftweb.Boot.boot(Boot.scala:21) ~[classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.6.
```

It's strange lift can't find the `db.properties`!

I've checked `target/webapp/WEB-INF/classes`, and `db.properties` is there! Where is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you posted should work - you might try

`val input = getClass.getResourceAsStream("/db.properties")`

Alternatively you might try the built-in Lift Props meccano:
http://www.assembla.com/wiki/show/liftweb/Properties

If you use Mapper (= persistence framework that comes with Lift) you might have a look at:
http://www.assembla.com/spaces/liftweb/wiki/Mapper

If everything fails - ask the friendly lift community:
http://groups.google.com/group/liftweb

Hope that helps
Paul

Comment: It's so strange, that in Java, to find a resource in classpath, we should use "db.properties", not "/db.properties"